# Performance Questions for Apache Beam with Big Windowed Timeseries Data from BigQuery

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery, apache-beam, tensorflow-datasets

I'm a first-time naive Beam user and have some questions. First I'll state the problem I'm trying to solve:

I have a BigQuery database with ~35 million rows of data of minutely timeseries data, across ~100k people. My goal is to create a TensorFlow Dataset (TFDS) where each example is a 2D Tensor of timeseries data that is 30 minutes long by ~50 features wide. These windows overlap each minute. For example. a user with data from 12:00 - 12:38 would have 10 examples each with 30 minutes of data, with the first window ranging 12:00-12:29 and the last 12:09-12:38.

I have a TFDS DatasetBuilder already written that works serially, which I've modified to use the built-in TFDS Beam support. I did this by creating a list of Pandas dataframes (stored in `combined_inputs` below), one for each user, and passing that into `beam.Create` then I apply a processing function (which does the windowing across an entire person's dataframe, imputation and formatting) via `beam.Flatmap` like so:

```
pcollection = beam.Create(combined_inputs)
transform = beam.FlatMap(lambda data: self._generate_examples(data[0],data[1],data[2]))
```

My problem is that I receive a MemoryError when I try to run this:

```
    write(payload)
MemoryError
```

**My questions**

1. I think I'm using Beam in a non-optimal way by passing in a list of Dataframes, correct?
2. Would it be more efficient to serialize that list of DataFrames to a GCS bucket (via pickle or parquet), then pass a list of filenames into beam.Create? If yes, is there a built in way to have beam do then deserialize those dataframes and pass them into my Flatmap function? Or should I deserialize the dataframes within my Flatmap function?
3. Or would it be more efficient to pass a list of userIDs to beam.Create and then query BigQuery per user within my Flatmap function and do all of the processing there?
4. Or do something completely different that I'm not thinking of? I did read a little bit about the Beam BigQuery I/O connector, but that operates on a single row, and I want to operate on windows, so I think this isn't the right solution?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.